# ValueMemberPath Binding in AutoCompleteBox WPF only returns top result in last name search?

Tags: wpf, autocompletebox

I have been using AutoCompleteBox in the WPF Toolkit and it just about meets all my needs, all except this troublesome `ValueMemberPath` binding. This is the value that the suggest box will auto complete by.

So I have this last name field, and when a user starts typing in a last name, I dynamically retrieve the top 10 results based on that. However, if the user types in 'Smith' and selects say the 4th name in the list, it always retrieves the first result in the suggestion list, because `ValueMemberPath` is set to filter by `LastName`. It always just thinks "Smith" is the first result even if there are 50 smiths with different first names.

I have been wracking my brain trying to figure out how to incorporate first name with this property. I tried to change `ValueMemberPath` to be a `FullName` field that equaled lastname, and firstname. The suggest box stops sorting as soon as a comma is entered, or if it is firstname 'space' lastname that doesn't work either.

I also ran into problems with `ValueMemberPath` because this value can't be changed dynamically, and there is bug where it is null while debugging: *[AutoCompleteBox Bug : ValueMemberPath is Null](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/585770/autocompletebox-bug-valuememberpath-is-null?ppud=0&wa=wsignin1.0)*.

I understand if no one has a complete solution. I just thought I would ask the question in case people run into this in the future and am not sure how to handle this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in the `AutoCompleteBox`.  Internal to the control the `ValueMemberPath` and `ValueMemberBinding` properties are implemented using a type called `BindingEvaluator`.  This class is a `FrameworkElement` that the `AutoCompleteBox` uses to do indirect value binding.

The problem is that when a `BindingEvaluator` is disconnected from the logical tree, binding doesn't work.  Here is how `AutoCompleteBox` needs to manage its `BindingEvaluator` in order for it to work:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataContext = new { FirstName = "Bill", LastName = "Smith" };
    var valueBindingEvaluator = new BindingEvaluator<string>();
    AddLogicalChild(valueBindingEvaluator);
    valueBindingEvaluator.ValueBinding = new Binding("FirstName");
    var value = valueBindingEvaluator.GetDynamicValue(DataContext);
}
```

This is a pretty easy bug to fix if you are willing to recompile the WPF Toolkit yourself.

```
public Binding ValueMemberBinding
{
    get
    {
        return _valueBindingEvaluator != null ?
            _valueBindingEvaluator.ValueBinding : null;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_valueBindingEvaluator == null)
        {
            _valueBindingEvaluator = new BindingEvaluator<string>();
            AddLogicalChild(_valueBindingEvaluator);
        }
        _valueBindingEvaluator.ValueBinding = value;
    }
}
```

This also fixes the bug you linked to.

Comment: thank you so much, i wasnt sure i would get an answer to this one. i am pretty new to WPF so im a little out of my element here. had to convert WPF Toolkit to 2010 and am digging in, found the 2nd function but not the first.

Comment: still not working for me, created the dll and pdb files and pasted them into my project however the valuememberpath is still null in debug mode.

Comment: If you referenced the recompiled version, you should be able to step into `acb.ValueMemberPath` = "LastName"` in the debugger.  If you can't, you're still using the old version.  Delete the old toolkit reference and then use Project -> References -> Browse to reference the one you compiled.