# Field Selection in WPF Designer - No Dropdown?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, .net-4.0, designer

Coming from a WinForms background, I'm a little surprised to see that most (if not all) of the field-related properties for things like `ItemsControl`s in WPF lack any sort of dropdown list for selecting fields.

For example, when using a `ComboBox`, if I bind the `ItemsSource` to a strongly-typed collection on my ViewModel in the designer, the `DisplayMemberPath` and `ValueMemberPath` properties require that I type in the names of the appropriate fields manually. My previous WinForms experience is that when binding to a strongly-typed list (in particular, a source that implements `ITypedList`), I would be given a dropdown of available fields so that there's no chance of fat-fingering the field name.

Am I doing something wrong here, or is this just not something that's been baked into WPF yet?

### Edit

I know that this functionality was provided by the `ITypedList` interface in WinForms, but my understanding was that the `System.ComponentModel` approach to binding (`PropertyDescriptor`s, `ITypedList`, `IBindingList`, and `IListSource`) were not used in WPF. Things like data grids seem to have no problems obtaining a list of fields to create columns, so I'm just curious if (and/or why) these properties that are intended to represent property names do not provide the same level of functionality.

Answer (score 2):

In WPF properties like `DisplayMemberPath` and `ValueMemberPath` aren't just properties - an example might be:

```
<ComboBox
    DisplayMemberPath="Addresses[0].Line1"
    ValueMemberPath="Address[0].Id"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=FavoriteAddressId}"
    ...
    />
```

If the designer properties only let you select from a list of properties, you'd be missing out on some pretty useful features. But you are right that providing a list in addition to being able to type it in would be useful.

There's always been a power struggle between WPF's binding system, which is quite dynamic, and the team's vision for tooling which requires a certain amount of rigidity. This is one of those cases that probably fell in the gap.

**Edit:** `PropertyDescriptors`, `IBindingList` and some other components of Windows Forms binding are used in WPF too - for example, my [MicroModels](http://www.paulstovell.com/micromodels-introduction) library relies on PropertyDescriptors to work, and is built for WPF. Silverlight however doesn't support many of these.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in the WPF toolkit. Check Stack Overflow question *[ValueMemberPath Binding in AutoCompleteBox WPF only returns top result in last name search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648527/valuememberpath-binding-in-autocompletebox-wpf-only-returns-top-result-in-last-na)*.

I think it has the answer to the problem.

Comment: Hm...this looks like it has more to do with a bug in a particular control. I'm not using the WPF toolkit, I'm really talking about *all* of the controls in WPF (both MS and third party, like DevExpress). While the WinForms counterparts of these controls would always expose a list of available properties for these special fields, it seems that the WPF designer does not.

Answer (score 0):

When setting the DataContext in code it is extremely difficult for the designer to determine the type that is being bound to.

When assigning the DataContext in [XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language) it is much easier and although there is no drop-down in the XAML editor, when you click the little square behind the property name in the properties box you can select the properties.

[image: Little post-it/square button]

[In addition you can even use a design-time datacontext to add design-time types and data (beta2 related post but still valid)](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/10/28/ddesigninstance-ddesigndata-in-visual-studio-2010-beta2/)

My guess it is a missing feature of the XAML-editor.

Comment: The OP's issue (and my issue) is not related to data binding (and, in my case, I'm using a design-time datacontext for binding, but that's not the issue here). The issue is related to fields like ValueMemberPath and DisplayMemberPath on something like a combobox.

Comment: I think it is caused by the same problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you're referring to; the data context is set in Xaml, which is why the bindings are listed. This is just a matter of the values not being available in a dropdown in the designer, not that the data is not readily available *to* the designer.

Comment: @Adam Robinson, the only way, that I know of, to set a DataContext to a strongly typed source is by pointing it to a StaticResource because then the designer could infer the type correctly. Can you give me another example? I might be ignorant of other ways and I am eager to learn.

Comment: For design purposes, I'm using the design-time method that you linked to. This allows me to specify a strongly-typed data context for use at design time, then the actual data context gets set in code.